# Get text from table

Tags: html

This table:

```
var tblusuario = document.getElementById('tbl_usuario_list');
    var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('Usuarios/');
    var rowindex = 1;

    databaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

            var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();

            var row = tblusuario.insertRow(rowindex);
            var cellId = row.insertCell(0);
            var cellboton = row.insertCell(1);


             cellId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childKey));
             cellboton.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs my-xs-btn" type="button" id="boton" value="childKey.innerText" onclick="hola()">'
                                      + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Eliminar</button>';


                rowindex = rowindex + 1;
           // }

        });
    });
```

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEEDr.png)

I want get the childkey in order to see in a alert, for that reason:

```
 function hola() {

         var id = document.getElementById('boton').value;
         alert(id);
      }
```

But the alert show: "childkey" . I want to see: "5bm00xdQlEdIKmmYQvWU5bgtvsU2"

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `childKey.innerText` inside double quotes, it acts as a `String` and not as a `variable`. And `childKey` is itself the text node so `childKey.innerText` will come undefined. Instead you need to use `cellId .innerText` or `childKey`

```js
var childKey = "ABSDBASDBSADDSA";
var tblusuario = document.getElementById('tbl_usuario_list');
var row = tblusuario.insertRow(0);
var cellId = row.insertCell(0);
var cellboton = row.insertCell(1);


cellId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childKey));
cellboton.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs my-xs-btn" type="button" id="boton" value="' + childKey + '" onclick="hola()">' +
  '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Eliminar</button>';

function hola() {
  var id = document.getElementById('boton').value;
  alert(id);
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl_usuario_list"></table>
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!

Comment: @Vidal Glad I helped